# Open loopback port for remote access

Tags: port, port-forwarding

I have a pyLoad machine in my local network which connects with autossh to my hosted virtual server so that I can access pyLoad from wherever I am.
Now I want to have access to the API port which is connected to the virtual server:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:65153          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

How can I make this port (which is only available on the localhost of the virtual server) accessible for remote connections?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't.  The 127.0.0.0/8 netblock is reserved and unroutable.

But you can tunnel to it.  From a remote machine, you could do

```
ssh virtualserver -L 12345:localhost:65153
```

and then, on your remote machine, local port 12345 will be connected through to virtualserver's port 65153.

But there's no way to make any machine's localhost accessible from off-server without using some kind of private network (VPN, ssh tunneling, proxy).

Comment: I solved it with a nginx proxy_pass argument for the webinterface port of pyLoad on port 8000 which is now accessible online on port 80 so I thought it must be possible for another port, too but not with nginx / a webserver!?

Comment: See above: VPN, ssh tunneling, proxy.  A decent webserver makes a fine proxy (see many comparable questions on SF).